# React-Table doesn't show data from firebase, but shows identical, handmade data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-table

I've been trying to make a locker organization / assignment app for a school project, and I've seen to hit a roadblock at the displaying of the firebase database. I found React-Table, which seemed like a good way to display the data, but I've had some issues actually displaying the data. When I run the app, it says that no rows are found.

Below is the code for my LockTable.js component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import 'firebase/database';
//import { database } from '../firebase';

import ReactTable from "react-table";
import 'react-table/react-table.css';

class LockTable extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        const database = firebase.database().ref("LockerList");
        const data1 = [];

        database.on('value',snapshot => {
            //Read each item in LockerList
            //Store it in a temporary array

            snapshot.forEach(childSnapShot => {
              //childSnapShot.key is the name of the data
              //childSnapShot.val() is the value of the data

              const Locker = {
                LockerNumber : childSnapShot.key.toString(), 
                Available : childSnapShot.val().Available,
                StudentName : childSnapShot.val().StudentName,
                StudentNumber : childSnapShot.val().StudentNumber.toString()    ,
                Period : childSnapShot.val().StudentPeriod.toString(),
                Teacher : childSnapShot.val().Teacher,
              };


              data1.push(childSnapShot.val());

            });
        });

        const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'Locker Number',
                accessor: 'LockerNumber'
            }, {
                Header: 'Available',
                accessor: 'Available',
            }, {
                Header: 'Student Name',
                accessor: 'StudentName',
            }, {
                Header: 'Student Number',
                accessor: 'StudentNumber',
            }, {
                Header: 'Period',
                accessor: 'Period',
            }, {
                Header: 'Teacher',
                accessor: 'Teacher',
            } ];

        console.log(data1);

        return(
            <div>
                <ReactTable
                    data={data1}
                    columns={columns}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default LockTable;
```

[This is what my firebase database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx2zE.png)

[This is what the data I read from firebase looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OwO1.png)

To test React-Table out, I made a StackBlitz with handmade variables rather than variables read from firebase. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-table-help

If you open the console, you can see that the data from the StackBlitz version is the exact same as the data from my version, yet, the StackBlitz version is displaying the data, while my version is not.

Does anyone know why my version doesn't work? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The render method can only handle synchronous logic. The firebase database logic is asynchronous, so to use it you can put it in `componentDidMount` instead and put the data in the component state when you get a snapshot.

**Example**

```
class LockTable extends Component {
  state = { data: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    const database = firebase.database().ref("LockerList");

    database.on("value", snapshot => {
      const data = [];

      snapshot.forEach(childSnapShot => {
        const locker = {
          LockerNumber: childSnapShot.key.toString(),
          Available: childSnapShot.val().Available,
          StudentName: childSnapShot.val().StudentName,
          StudentNumber: childSnapShot.val().StudentNumber.toString(),
          Period: childSnapShot.val().StudentPeriod.toString(),
          Teacher: childSnapShot.val().Teacher
        };

        data.push(locker);
      });

      this.setState(prevState => {
        return { data: [...prevState.data, ...data] };
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const columns = [
      {
        Header: "Locker Number",
        accessor: "LockerNumber"
      },
      {
        Header: "Available",
        accessor: "Available"
      },
      {
        Header: "Student Name",
        accessor: "StudentName"
      },
      {
        Header: "Student Number",
        accessor: "StudentNumber"
      },
      {
        Header: "Period",
        accessor: "Period"
      },
      {
        Header: "Teacher",
        accessor: "Teacher"
      }
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactTable data={this.state.data} columns={columns} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent more than an hour trying to debug this before coming here, where it got answered in around three minutes! I should come here more often.